# Scrollable Relative Layout with ImageViews

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a scrollbar to my RelativeLayout, which contains 5 ImageViews.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="XXX" >

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/picture_imgvw_pic1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showPictureZoomDialog"
        android:src="@drawable/XXX"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/picture_imgvw_pic2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture_imgvw_pic1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showPictureZoomDialog" 
        android:src="@drawable/XXX"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/picture_imgvw_pic3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture_imgvw_pic2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showPictureZoomDialog" 
        android:src="@drawable/XXX"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/picture_imgvw_pic4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture_imgvw_pic3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showPictureZoomDialog" 
        android:src="@drawable/XXX"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/picture_imgvw_pic5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture_imgvw_pic4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showPictureZoomDialog" 
        android:src="@drawable/XXX"/>                   

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/picture_button_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/picture_button_next"
    android:onClick="buttonNext"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This got me displayed 4 of the 5 ImageViews, nothing scrollable. What am I missing? Maybe anything like a "visible attribute"?
thx :)

Comment: It looks like some of your XML is missing. Please post the rest of your layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the height of your RelativeLayout. It is set to "match_parent". You should set it to "wrap_content" like so :

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

When set to match_parent, the RelativeLayout will never be higher than the ScrollView and hence no scroll is possible.

***Edit:*** Apparently you want to scroll horizontally so you should use an HorizontalScrollView instead of a ScrollView and it's the width of your RelativeLayout that should be "wrap_content"